# How to draw UILabel with padding text not hidden?

Tags: ios

I will drawing UILabel with code

```
CustomLabel *label = [[CustomLabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 260, 100)];
label.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor redColor] CGColor];
label.layer.borderWidth = 3.0;
[label setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:16]];
CALayer * l1 = [label layer];
[l1 setMasksToBounds:YES];
[l1 setCornerRadius:10.0];

label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft; // UITextAlignmentCenter, UITextAlignmentLeft
label.textColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
label.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
label.numberOfLines=4;
label.lineBreakMode=NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", message];
label.tag = index;


[label sizeToFit];
```

And of course, i will found a solution from stackoverflow for create padding for label
with code

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        self.edgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(5,5,5,5); //customize padding here
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)drawTextInRect:(CGRect)rect {
    [super drawTextInRect:UIEdgeInsetsInsetRect(rect, self.edgeInsets)];
}
```

Everything working fine, but text in my label showing not good, here is my label screenshot.

[image]

I want like this.

[image]

Please help and thanks for your time.

Comment: Checkout [this](http://www.jessesquires.com/JSQMessagesViewController/) and [this](https://github.com/SocialObjects-Software/SOMessaging) may be it will help

Comment: I will check your link and very helping me in work, thanks so much.

Answer (score 1):

you would want to have a look into this library.. its awesome and totally configurable...
https://github.com/AlexBarinov/UIBubbleTableView